# Remove line item from order by API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to remove line item from order and add new variant in the order when order is placed. but there is no api for deleting line item from order

I have tried with below article

https://shopify.dev/apps/fulfillment/order-management-apps/order-editing#add-a-new-variant

Did not find any API for removing line item

Comment: You cannot remove a line from an order. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Line Item From Order By API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864270/remove-line-item-from-order-by-api)

Comment: I am making the partial & full payment process when order si created with partial payment after that partial i need to remove that product and add that product with full pay that will calculate into report. @FabioFilippi

Comment: So you might want to create a refund instead? https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/refund#post-orders-order-id-refunds

Comment: I need to remove that product from order and add any other product in that order. Please let me know any API regarding this @FabioFilippi

Comment: There is none. Good luck.

Comment: @FabioFilippi
can we edit order total by API

Answer (score 0):

Like @FabioFilippi said, you can't do that without a refund. From the customer perspective, imagine you have paid for items A and B, and as a result of some backend service, you get only A or A & C. That could be considered a scam.

From the Shopify perspective that would mess up their backend badly because there are such things as webhooks and email notifications. That could probably affect negatively analytics.

Your best option is to refund items. A better choice would be to revalidate business requirements.

Side note: please do not spam.

Comment: can we edit order total by API

Comment: If you are using Shopify Plus you can check Script Editor or for other plans Shopify Function Discounts API. But after an order is placed you can't mutate it without anyone noticing it.

Comment: I want to change order total after place the order by graphql API or REST API
Is it possible ?